# Adjunctions between discrete categories

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

[Exercise 2.1.13](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf) asks:

> What can be said about adjunctions between discrete categories?

First of all, what is "adjunction between categories"? Adjunctions between *functors* were defined on p.41. Is "adjunctions between discrete categories" supposed to mean "adjunctions between functors between discrete categories"?

Secondly, even if we interpret "adjunctions between discrete categories" as I wrote above, what kind of answer is expected from me? I don't think there is any "positive" result. For example, let $Ob(A)=\{a,a',a''\}, Ob(B)=\{b,b'\}$. Consider the functor $F:a,a'\mapsto b; a''\mapsto b'$ and $G:b\mapsto a', b''\mapsto a$. There is no bijection $B(F(a''),b')\cong A(a'',G(b))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the upshot of the discussion with Max. (Corrections are welcome.)

First of all, since Leinster only defines adjunctions between *functors*, the question should ask about adjunctions between *functors* between discrete categories.

*Main Claim.* Let  $\mathscr A$ and $\mathscr B$ be discrete categories and let $F:\mathscr A\to\mathscr B$ and $G:\mathscr B\to\mathscr A$ be functors. Then $F \dashv G $ iff $$(F:Ob(\mathscr A)\to Ob(\mathscr B), G:Ob(\mathscr B)\to Ob(\mathscr A))$$ is a pair of mutually inverse bijections.

Suppose $F\dashv G$. Then $$\mathscr B(F(A),B)\cong\mathscr A(A,G(B))$$ for all objects $A$ of $\mathscr A$ and $B$ of $\mathscr B$. In particular, if $B=F(A)$, then the LHS of the above has exactly one element. Thus so does the RHS. That is, there is exactly one arrow $A\to GF(A)$ in $\mathscr A$. This implies that $A=GF(A)$. Since $A$ was arbitrary, this shows that $GF=1_A$. Similarly one can show that $FG=1_B$. That is, $F$ and $G$ are mutually inverse bijections.

Now suppose that $F$ and $G$ are mutually inverse bijections. Consider an arrow $F(A)\to B$ in $\mathscr B$. The existence of this arrow implies $F(A)=B$. Now $A=GF(A)=G(B)$. Thus there is (exactly one, namely identity) arrow $A\to G(B)$ in $\mathscr A$. And conversely, if there is an arrow $A\to G(B)$ in $\mathscr A$, then $A=G(B)$, and $B=FG(B)=F(A)$, so there is a (unique) arrow $F(A)\to B$ in $\mathscr B$. This proves that there is a bijection $\mathscr B(F(A),B)\cong\mathscr A(A,G(B))$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is what's meant. When people say "an adjunction", they usually mean "a pair of functors $(F,G)$ with a natural isomorphism such that blabla"

Secondly, your example is an example of something that isn't an adjunction. 
In fact, there is a positive result : to get that result you have to answer these :

1) What is a functor between discrete categories ?

2) You have an isomorphism $A(a,G(b)) \simeq B(F(a),b)$. What does this imply with $b=F(a)$, in a discrete category ?

(this 2) is a shadow of the more general notion of the *unit* of an adjunction, and the *counit*)

Comment: *When people say "an adjunction", they usually mean "a pair of functors $(F,G)$ with a natural isomorphism such that blabla"* Okay, but Leinster only defines an adjunction between functors $F:A\to B$ and $G:B\to A$ (as a choice of an isomorphism $A(F(a),b)\cong B(a,G(B))$) but not between categories, which caused confusion. Regarding your questions, that were the questions I asked myself originally. A functor between discrete categories $A$ and $B$ is just a function that assigns to objects of $A$ some objects of $B$. If $b=F(a)$, then $B(F(a),b)$ is a singleton (and if not, it's empty). TBC..

Comment: ... In the former case $a=G(b)$ and in the latter case $A\ne G(b)$. But I still don't see what kind of positive result one can extract from here.

Comment: Yes, I agree that that's what you said, the quoted passage was to answer your concern and explain what Leinster most likely meant. Then you are right about 1). About 2), I said "try with $b=F(a)$"

Comment: If $b=F(a)$, then $B(F(a),b)$ is a singleton. Hence so is $A(a,G(b))$. Therefore $GF=1_A$, right? And if $a=G(b)$ this gives $FG=1_B$. So if $F\dashv G$, then $F$ is an isomorphism in the category of functors from $A$ to $B$. Is it the expected answer?

Comment: I would phrase it as "if $F\dashv G$, $(F,G)$ is an inverse pair of bijections/isomorphisms". Can you give a converse ?

Comment: I'm not sure about the converse. For example, one has to assign bijectively to an arrow $F(a)\to b$ an arrow $a\to G(b)$ for arbitrary $a\in A,b\in B$. We only know that $a=G(b'),b=F(a')$ for some $a',b'$, but I don't see how to use it.

Comment: Well assume there is an arrow $F(a)\to b$. Then $F(a) = b$. So $a= GF(a) = G(b)$, so there is an arrow $a\to G(b)$. The arrows in question are unique, etc.